# How to avoid hitting pointcut twice when the cut is on a superclass, but a derived class overrides?

Tags: java, aspectj, super, aspect, pointcut

It's tough to make a concise title for this.

Anyway, imagine I have a parent class:

```
    public class Shape {
        public Dimensions getDimensions() {
            // Does some generic stuff.
        }
    }
```

I have a derived class from it that overrides the getDimensions method:

```
    public class Circle extends Shape {
        public Dimensions getDimensions() {
            // Does some stuff.
            super.getDimensions();
        }
    }
```

When I create an aspect with a pointcut on `Shape.getDimensions`, the pointcut is hit twice when `Circle.getDimensions` is called: once for `Circle.getDimensions`, then once when it calls `super.getDimensions`.

The pointcut looks something like this: `@Pointcut("execution(* Shape.getDimensions(..))")`

I've added a hack inside the advice to check the declaring type's name (using `JoinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType().getName()`), but I find it rather gross and it feels kind of like a hack. I figure there MUST be a better way to do this.

Is there?

Apologies if the formatting isn't very good. First time asking a question on here (I can usually find the answer already).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you meant that your pointcut uses `Shape+.getDimensions()` (with the plus sign), otherwise it would not have matched `Circle` at all.

Anyway, you can solve the problem like this (I hope native AspectJ syntax is okay for you, I find it so much clearer and more expressive):

```java
public aspect ShapeAspect {
    pointcut getDimensions() : execution(* Shape+.getDimensions());
    pointcut getDimensionsNoSuper() : getDimensions() && !cflowbelow(getDimensions());

    after() : getDimensionsNoSuper() {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully, thanks. I'm more used to the annotation style, but the key was the cflowbelow call. In the process of trying to figure out if I could condense that into a single advice (couldn't figure it out), I found this lovely appendix: http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html

Comment: I apparently need 15 points to do so. I only have 11. Believe me, I tried! :(

Comment: actually `execution` would also match superclass method,no matter if there is a `+`

Comment: @Sean: This is why the pointcut has another condition which filters out the execution of the superclass method. Have you even tried?